# What does 'G.depth = ()' mean in Python 3.10?

Tags: python, networkx, wordnet, python-3.10

Trying to use WordNet and NetworkX in a plot using MatPlotLib Python 3.10 library

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> import matplotlib
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> def traverse(graph, start, node):
...     graph.depth[node.name] = node.shortest_path_distance(start)
...     for child in node.hyponyms():
...             graph.add.edge(node.name, child.name)
...             traverse(graph, start, child)
...
>>> def hyponym_graph(start):
...     G = nx.Graph()
...     G.depth = ()
...     traverse(G, start, start)
...     return G

>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download('omw-1.4')
[nltk_data] Downloading package omw-1.4 to
[nltk_data]     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data...
True
```

Using WordNet Text Corpus to build the Graph

```
>>> dog = wn.synset('dog.n.01')
>>> graph = hyponym_graph(dog)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in hyponym_graph
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in traverse
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
>
```

Answer (score 0):

`G.depth = ()` is creating a new property (named `depth`) on the graph `G` and setting it equal to `()`, an empty tuple.

Here's how that property is being used inside the `traverse` function, though:

```
graph.depth[node.name] = node.shortest_path_distance(start)
```

Based on that and the error message you're getting, `TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment`, I think you probably want to initialize the `depth` property to an empty `dict` instead of an empty tuple.

```
G.depth = {}
```

or

```
G.depth = dict()
```